# How to place one particular element from an XML array into an FO object?

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

XML Code:

```
<EUseSummary>
    <Name>EUSummary</Name>
    <Title1 index="1">Proposed</Title1>
    <Title1 index="2">Proposed</Title1>
    <Title1 index="3">Proposed</Title1>
    <Title1 index="4">Standard</Title1>
    <Title1 index="5">Standard</Title1>
    <Title1 index="6">Standard</Title1>
    <Title1 index="7">Compliance</Title1>
    <Title1 index="8">CAHP</Title1>
    <Title2 index="1">Design</Title2>
    <Title2 index="2">Design</Title2>
    <Title2 index="3">Design</Title2>
    <Title2 index="4">Design</Title2>
    <Title2 index="5">Design</Title2>
    <Title2 index="6">Design</Title2>
    <Title2 index="7">Margin</Title2>
    <Title2 index="8">Design</Title2>
    <Title3 index="0">End Use</Title3>
    <Title3 index="1">Site (kWh)</Title3>
    <Title3 index="2">Site (therms)</Title3>
    <Title3 index="3">(kTDV/ft²-yr)</Title3>
    <Title3 index="4">Site (kWh)</Title3>
    <Title3 index="5">Site (therms)</Title3>
    <Title3 index="6">(kTDV/ft²-yr)</Title3>
    <Title3 index="7">(kTDV/ft²-yr)</Title3>
    <Title3 index="8">(kTDV/ft²-yr)</Title3>
    <Enduse1 index="0">Space Heating</Enduse1>
    <Enduse1 index="1">246</Enduse1>
    <Enduse1 index="2">286.5</Enduse1>
    <Enduse1 index="3">21.04</Enduse1>
    <Enduse1 index="4">255</Enduse1>
    <Enduse1 index="5">296.8</Enduse1>
    <Enduse1 index="6">21.80</Enduse1>
    <Enduse1 index="7">0.76</Enduse1>
    <Enduse1 index="8">23.18</Enduse1>
  </EUseSummary>
```

A small piece of my XSL code is pasted below. This is defining one cell within a table. I will ultimately want to grab all Enduse values at position index=8 and place in the remaining cells of the table. For now, I just need some clarification as to how to select a specific value from the  object of the XML:

```
<fo:table-row  xsl:use-attribute-sets="Row">
      <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="dataCell">
      <fo:block> 
         <xsl:value-of select="/SDDXML/Model/Proj/EUseSummary/Enduse1/*[@index=8]"/>                                                                                                                                                                                      
      </fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
```

What I'm expecting to return is a cell value (within a larger table that I haven't provided code for) of: 23.18

Thanks,

Comment: Grab a good book on XSL and read it. Do a template match on Enduse1[@index='8'] ...

Answer (score 1):

Your current xpath ends in this...

```
Enduse1/*[@index=8]
```

But the `/*` means it is looking for a child element under **Enduse1** of which there are none! There is only a text node, not an element.

Try this instead:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/SDDXML/Model/Proj/EUseSummary/Enduse1[@index=8]"/>
```